# Git Push accessibility error of repository

Tags: git, github

Error:

```
D:\flutter_app\tut1>git push -u origin master
The authenticity of host 'github.com (13.234.176.102)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? y
Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint: yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,13.234.176.102' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**Here's What I did:**

```
git init   //(In correct directory)

git add .           

git status   //(every thing green)   
 
git config --global user.name "name"

git config --global user.email "email"

git commit -m "commit name"        
       
git push -u origin master
```

Repository exist that i can assure you.

I have never pushed an entire project, only single file so is there any other process for it because it has few folders also.

**PS: I also tried pushing using VS code but it also showed access denied, repo is public by the way**

Comment: What kind of push protocol are you using? Have you authenticated correctly?

Comment: @Dev Please check the user with which you are pushing the code has permissions for the repository. Another that you should check is `git remote -v`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two remote lines (ssh and https). You have chosen the ssh remote line, because https never show RSA pubkey. So try choosing the https remote line.